# Validate year with current year using Lombok

Tags: spring-data-jpa, bean-validation, lombok

In my application, I have a field name 'year' contains only year(2016, 2015 .....). But I have to validate this 'year' field, this field should contain current year.

I check all the Lombok validation annotations, but I did not find any annotation help to me. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You mean you have a setter for year and need to check if the input is valid? Just do it in code if there is no Bean Validation API annotation to do that

Comment: If this field always contains current year, why you need it? Maybe you just hardcode it as `new Date()` or something like this?

Answer (score 2):

I think there aren't lombok validation constraint annotations. If there are I didn't know.

I assume your field is a Integer. So, I suggest you next solutions:

#### Solution 1 - java bean validation constraint Annotations

You could add a method which start by 'is'like next and add java validation constraint @assertTrue

```
private int year;

@AssertTrue
public boolean isCurrentYear(){
    return LocalDate.now().getYear() == year;
}
```

#### Solution 2 - Programmatically

Create a method to protect your constructor, setter or both checking if the year integer is the current year:

```
private int year;

//Constructor
public YourClass(int year){
    checkCurrentYear(year);
    this.year = year;
}

//Setter    
public void setYear(int year){
    checkCurrentYear(year);
    this.year= year;
}

public void checkCurrentYear(int year){
    if(!isCurrentYear()) // or (LocalDate.now().getYear() != year)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Year must be the current");
}
```

#### Solution 3 - Implement your Spring Validator

Implement spring validator interface and use it when you want:

```
public class YourClass implements Validator {

   public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
      return YourClass.class.equals(clazz);
   }

   public void validate(Object obj, Errors e) {

    YourClass p = (YourClass) obj;
    if (LocalDate.now().getYear() != p.getYear()) {
        e.rejectValue("year", "notcurrentyear");
    } 
   }
}
```